# ArgumentExeption is unhandled when converting base64 to image

Tags: c#, base64

i am trying to convert image from base64 . When i run this code i get the error ArgumentException is unhandeled parameter is not valid . Below is my code

```
public void LoadImage()
    {
      string bytes = "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";
        Base64ToImage(bytes);
    }

 public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
    {

        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]

        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);


        // Convert byte[] to Image

        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

       Image image1 = Image.FromStream(ms, true); // here error is generating 

        return image1;

    }
```

Comment: Can you give us the exact exception message you're getting?

Comment: @aevitas Parameter is not valid. this is giving

Comment: There should be a message or an inner exception tell you *which* parameter is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this line is more than enough, because it will create memory stream with image bytes.:

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
```

So this one is not needed as all bytes are already in the stream:

```
 ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
```

To position the stream at its start replace the previous line with seek call:

```
  ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

**EDIT**

Maybe it has something to do with string or the format used, because with image created in place it works well:

```
static public void LoadImage()
{
    String bytes = CreateImageBase64();
    Base64ToImage(bytes);
}

static public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{

    // Convert Base64 String to byte[]

    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    Image image1 = Image.FromStream(ms, true); // here error is generating 

    return image1;
}


static String CreateImageBase64()
{
    //Create image
    Image image = new Bitmap(3, 3);

    //Save to stream
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    //Save to byte array
    Byte[] imageBytes = new Byte[ms.Length];            
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    ms.Read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    //Save to Base64
    String base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

    return base64Image;
}

...
LoadImage();
```

**EDIT:**

When I've used `Encoding.ASCII.GetChars()` on the array converted from Base64 string I got:

```
??\0sr\0*com.ups.ecis.core.shipments.ShipmentDigest\n^?2??\0 Z\0isABRReturnedinResponseZ\0isABRUserIneligibleZ\0isAIAZ\0isCN22NumberPresentZ\0isCN22RequestedZ\0isCombinedMIandLabe
```

It looks a bit strange for an image(of course if it does not contain enormous amounts of metadata). Maybe you can show the original xml. Who knows, the xml tag can be misnamed or misused.

Comment: Error again `Parameter is not valid.`

Comment: I've tried. Well, are you sure that the string in LoadImage is correct Base64 Image? From where have you got it?

Comment: Image image1 = Image.FromStream(ms, true); on this line of code

Comment: yes this is Correct Base64 image i am getting from UPS API

Comment: I mean from where have you got the rO0ABXNyACpjb20udXBzLmVjaXMuY2 line?

Comment: i got this line form XML of UPS webservice

Comment: And what is the format of the image? Does web service specifies it? Or is it just raw data string? Because image class does not support everything. And the webservice may use some specific encoding that is not known to Image class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56350/discussion-between-a-goutam-and-eugene-podskal).

Answer (score 0):

Try This (If you want to set image directly to Image Control)

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
        img.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```